# Output Changing from JFrame to Java Result

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have been running a JFrame in NetBeans to test it and all of a sudden the output changed from a display of the JFrame to:

`Java Result: -1073740940`

I do not know what caused this as I did not change anything in the `run` method and it is effecting all of my JFrame programs. Does anybody have any idea what is causing this? Is it a glitch in the program or did I accidentally toggled a setting NetBeans has that I'm not aware of?

UPDATE:

Here is the code to the program as requested by someone, but as I stated before it affects multiple projects that use a JFrame

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package imeannumbers;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author Kanto Ruki
 */
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Main
     */
    boolean decimalUsed = false;

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tabGrouping = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        tabNumPad = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnOne = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnTwo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnThree = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnFour = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnFive = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnSix = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnSeven = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnEight = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnNine = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnDecimal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnZero = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnEnter = new javax.swing.JButton();
        tabAchievements = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lbl00 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl01 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl03 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl05 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl07 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("I Mean Numbers");

        txtBox.setEditable(false);
        txtBox.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        txtBox.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.LOWERED));

        btnOne.setText("1");
        btnOne.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnOneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnTwo.setText("2");
        btnTwo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnTwoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnThree.setText("3");
        btnThree.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnThreeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnFour.setText("4");
        btnFour.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnFourActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnFive.setText("5");
        btnFive.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnFiveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnSix.setText("6");
        btnSix.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSixActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnSeven.setText("7");
        btnSeven.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSevenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnEight.setText("8");
        btnEight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEightActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnNine.setText("9");
        btnNine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnNineActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnDecimal.setText(".");
        btnDecimal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDecimalActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnZero.setText("0");
        btnZero.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnZeroActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnEnter.setText("Enter");
        btnEnter.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEnterActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout tabNumPadLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(tabNumPad);
        tabNumPad.setLayout(tabNumPadLayout);
        tabNumPadLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnDecimal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnZero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnEnter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnSeven, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnEight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnNine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnFour, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnFive, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnSix, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnTwo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnThree, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(txtBox))
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        tabNumPadLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(txtBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnOne, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnTwo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnThree, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnFour, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnFive, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnSix, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnSeven, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnEight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnNine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(tabNumPadLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnDecimal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnZero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnEnter, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        tabGrouping.addTab("NumPad", tabNumPad);

        lbl00.setText("??");
        lbl00.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        lbl01.setText("??");
        lbl01.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        lbl03.setText("??");
        lbl03.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        lbl05.setText("??");
        lbl05.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        lbl07.setText("??");
        lbl07.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        lbl13.setText("??");
        lbl13.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "?????", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbl05, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl07, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbl00, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl01, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl03, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lbl03)
                    .addComponent(lbl01)
                    .addComponent(lbl00))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(lbl05)
                    .addComponent(lbl07)
                    .addComponent(lbl13))
                .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        tabAchievements.setViewportView(jPanel1);

        tabGrouping.addTab("Achievements", tabAchievements);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 390, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 232, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        tabGrouping.addTab("How To Play", jPanel3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 390, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 232, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        tabGrouping.addTab("About", jPanel4);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabGrouping)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabGrouping)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "1");
    }                                      

    private void btnTwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "2");
    }                                      

    private void btnThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "3");
    }                                        

    private void btnFourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "4");
    }                                       

    private void btnFiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "5");
    }                                       

    private void btnSixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "6");
    }                                      

    private void btnSevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "7");
    }                                        

    private void btnEightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "8");
    }                                        

    private void btnNineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "9");
    }                                       

    private void btnDecimalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (!decimalUsed) {
            txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + ".");
            decimalUsed = true;
        }
    }                                          

    private void btnZeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        txtBox.setText(txtBox.getText() + "0");
    }                                       

    private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String check = txtBox.getText();

        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("title");
        title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.RIGHT);
        title.setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.BOTTOM);

        switch (check) {
            case "00":
                title.setTitle("The Beginning...");
                lbl00.setBorder(title);
                lbl00.setText("00");
                break;
            case "01":
                title.setTitle("Your the First");
                lbl01.setBorder(title);
                lbl01.setText("01");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        decimalUsed = false;
        txtBox.setText("");
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDecimal;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEight;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEnter;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFive;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFour;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnNine;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnOne;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSeven;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSix;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnThree;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnTwo;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnZero;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl00;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl01;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl03;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl05;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl07;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl13;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane tabAchievements;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabGrouping;
    private javax.swing.JPanel tabNumPad;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBox;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

UPDATE2:

Thanks to @Willshackleford, I found that the problem is occurring in the **main** execution in the EventQueue

```
public static void invokeLater(Runnable runnable) {
    Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(
        new InvocationEvent(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(), runnable));
}
```

With the Error Message `Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option`

Comment: No offense but we cannot possibly magically see your code. Please have a look at [ask] and improve your question. As is, it is pretty likely to get closed.

Comment: @Fildor I have added code of one of the programs affected. I hope it helps

Comment: Last time I used swing was decades ago, so I'm not the best source. But I have the feeling you should have a look at Oracle's Swing Tutorials and how they build main methods for Swing Applications.

Comment: The advice linked by @Fildor includes *"Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."* The part that reads 'just enough' means (for something like this) around 50-100 lines of code. The code posted is more than 450 LOC.  Trim it if you seriously want help. Am voting to close on the basis 'no MCVE'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have stated before that the program doesn't seem to be running any errors as this is repeating for different JFrame applets that were built prior to this problem occurring. I'm more suspicious about Netbeans doing something that I am not aware of. And what does 'no MCVE' stand for in this situation?

Comment: Stands for "no [mcve]" in any situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may have toggled a setting. If you select your project, and choose Properties in the pop-up menu and then select the category run. There are a couple of properties that would mess things up. The main class could be changed to a class other than your JFrame class. Setting the platform to a JDK version you don't have installed or have a broken installation for etc.

Probably the best way to debug would be to select the project and choose Debug -> Step Into or press F7 from them menu. This will start your program but immediately pause it so you can step through it one line at a time by pressing F7 (Step Into)  or F8 (Step Over) for each line. If it starts stepping into the wrong class you will no you  need to fix the main class property. If it starts ok but exits early you will want to look carefully at the last line before it exits.

Comment: The error seems to be `Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option` from stepping into the `main` runner

Comment: In the project properties dialog, select Compiling under Build in the categories list and then check the checkbox labelled 'Generate Debugging Info' and recompile.

Comment: By default, the program already has the 'Generate Debugging Info', thought I went and tried recompiling without before compiling it with the Info again. This did not produce any changes that I could find...